# LogCat spouts error messages when I plug in my phone

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, sony-xperia

Sometimes when I plug in my phone, a Sony Xperia Z1 Compact, LogCat just spouts out a ton of errors. <del>It is also not possible to use my phone as debugging device, since the app I load just crashes instantly.</del> (edit: turned out not to be true, read below)

The error messages look like this:

```
07-12 23:18:55.265: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:20:12.541: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:20:12.561: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:20:12.571: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:20:16.054: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:20:32.830: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:20:44.336: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:21:12.921: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:22:00.704: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:22:25.382: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:22:25.692: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:22:33.952: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:22:55.661: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:22:55.681: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:23:05.529: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:23:15.739: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:24:00.019: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:25:54.060: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:26:36.818: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:27:32.822: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:28:39.999: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:28:40.205: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:28:40.225: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:39.014: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:39.044: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:39.054: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:39.074: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:50.331: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:53.469: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:29:53.689: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:30:02.339: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:30:25.584: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:31:05.822: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:31:12.781: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:31:14.029: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:31:14.059: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:31:57.845: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:31:59.899: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:32:01.130: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:32:01.150: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:32:31.592: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:32:35.234: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:33:23.051: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:33:29.426: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:33:29.456: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:33:29.476: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:33:46.025: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:34:29.660: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:36:14.409: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:36:40.518: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:37:05.328: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:37:15.407: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:37:15.497: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:37:41.136: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:38:20.476: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:38:20.496: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:38:29.223: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:38:53.173: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:39:43.142: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:40:02.593: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:40:06.861: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:40:13.454: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:40:16.022: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:41:16.565: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:43:26.747: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:43:40.574: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:44:01.703: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:44:08.517: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:44:14.047: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:44:15.376: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:44:20.182: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:44:30.273: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:45:36.666: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:45:37.084: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:46:10.845: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-12 23:53:46.914: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-13 00:01:27.358: E/ActivityThread(7274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.MessagesForegroundProvider
07-13 01:07:42.691: E/QcConnectivityService(1023): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '778 interface route remove rmnet0 default 0.0.0.0 0 10.64.247.244' failed with '400 778 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
07-13 06:09:43.122: E/QcConnectivityService(1023): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '827 interface route remove rmnet0 default 0.0.0.0 0 10.51.73.24' failed with '400 827 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
07-13 07:24:23.578: E/QcConnectivityService(1023): Unexpected mtu value: android.net.wifi.WifiStateTracker@437adea0
07-13 11:04:31.762: E/QcConnectivityService(1023): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '883 interface route remove rmnet0 default 0.0.0.0 0 10.64.4.5' failed with '400 883 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
07-13 11:11:42.870: E/QcConnectivityService(1023): Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '912 interface route remove rmnet0 default 0.0.0.0 0 10.66.186.82' failed with '400 912 Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)'
07-13 11:29:45.860: E/GpsXtraDownloader(1023): No XTRA servers were specified in the GPS configuration
07-13 11:32:57.469: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:32:57.469: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:33:27.310: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:33:27.310: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:34:38.441: E/Diag_Lib(804): [IMS_FATAL]| 2912 | 818 |ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>
07-13 11:40:26.524: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:26.524: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:27.494: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:27.494: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:29.744: E/InputEventModelImpl(1590): onStartInput event aborted: com.touchtype.keyboard.inputeventmodel.ExtractedTextUnavailableException: could not obtain extracted text (class com.touchtype.keyboard.inputeventmodel.ExtractedTextUnavailableException)
07-13 11:40:29.754: E/Diag_Lib(804): [IMS_FATAL]| 2912 | 818 |ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>
07-13 11:40:29.794: E/IceButton(1360): ICE setting not found
07-13 11:40:36.212: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:36.212: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): ClassNotFoundException
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getHWConfigRevision(DefCapUpdaterService.java:302)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getInfo(DefCapUpdaterService.java:292)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.access$1000(DefCapUpdaterService.java:66)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.doWrite(DefCapUpdaterService.java:682)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(DefCapUpdaterService.java:735)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sonymobile/devicesecurity/HWConfRevision
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/semc_bootinfoif.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/DefaultCapabilities.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/DefaultCapabilities, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-13 11:40:41.002: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:40:41.862: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:41.862: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:44.892: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:44.892: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): ClassNotFoundException
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getHWConfigRevision(DefCapUpdaterService.java:302)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getInfo(DefCapUpdaterService.java:292)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.access$1000(DefCapUpdaterService.java:66)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.doWrite(DefCapUpdaterService.java:682)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(DefCapUpdaterService.java:735)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sonymobile/devicesecurity/HWConfRevision
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/semc_bootinfoif.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/DefaultCapabilities.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/DefaultCapabilities, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-13 11:40:45.652: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:40:53.962: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:53.962: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:56.982: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:40:56.982: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:41:04.092: E/Cryptfs(297): not running with encryption, aborting
07-13 11:41:06.022: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:41:06.022: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023): got -1 reading
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023): Communication error: 
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023): java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:33)
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:98)
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:84)
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at com.android.server.usb.UsbDebuggingManager.listenToSocket(UsbDebuggingManager.java:81)
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at com.android.server.usb.UsbDebuggingManager.run(UsbDebuggingManager.java:111)
07-13 11:41:06.332: E/UsbDebuggingManager(1023):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): ClassNotFoundException
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getHWConfigRevision(DefCapUpdaterService.java:302)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getInfo(DefCapUpdaterService.java:292)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.access$1000(DefCapUpdaterService.java:66)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.doWrite(DefCapUpdaterService.java:682)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(DefCapUpdaterService.java:735)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sonymobile/devicesecurity/HWConfRevision
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/semc_bootinfoif.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/DefaultCapabilities.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/DefaultCapabilities, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-13 11:41:06.672: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): ClassNotFoundException
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getHWConfigRevision(DefCapUpdaterService.java:302)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.getInfo(DefCapUpdaterService.java:292)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService.access$1000(DefCapUpdaterService.java:66)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.doWrite(DefCapUpdaterService.java:682)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at com.sonyericsson.capabilities.DefCapUpdaterService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(DefCapUpdaterService.java:735)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sonymobile/devicesecurity/HWConfRevision
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sonymobile.devicesecurity.HWConfRevision" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/semc_bootinfoif.jar", zip file "/system/priv-app/DefaultCapabilities.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/DefaultCapabilities, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-13 11:41:08.162: E/DefCapUpdaterService(24057):  ... 11 more
07-13 11:41:09.042: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:41:09.042: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:41:23.862: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:41:23.862: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:42:10.012: E/Diag_Lib(804): [IMS_FATAL]| 2912 | 818 |ims-rtp-daemon ims_rtp_qmi_handler_thread_func waiting on select thread>
07-13 11:42:10.082: E/InputEventModelImpl(1590): onStartInput event aborted: com.touchtype.keyboard.inputeventmodel.ExtractedTextUnavailableException: could not obtain extracted text (class com.touchtype.keyboard.inputeventmodel.ExtractedTextUnavailableException)
07-13 11:42:15.812: E/IceButton(1360): ICE setting not found
07-13 11:42:27.882: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(24582): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
07-13 11:43:13.842: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:13.842: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:16.222: E/Cryptfs(297): not running with encryption, aborting
07-13 11:43:19.442: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:19.442: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:21.562: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:21.562: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:22.462: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:22.462: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:22.772: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24582): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-13 11:43:22.772: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24582): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-13 11:43:22.792: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24582): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-13 11:43:22.792: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24582): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-13 11:43:25.292: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24582): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-13 11:43:25.292: E/SpannableStringBuilder(24582): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-13 11:43:25.482: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
07-13 11:43:25.482: E/Parcel(426): Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

... and so on. This is only part of the error messages, because of the StackOverflow message limit. When I plug in, it instantly spouts out all these error messages and when keeping the phone plugged in it sporadically gives me more error messages.

Something seems to be fundamentally wrong but I can't figure out what. This does not always happen when I plug in my phone and sometimes it works fine. I would be very grateful for some help!

I am using Lubuntu 14.04, Eclipse Juno and everything from the ADT bundle.

**EDIT**: Seems that it actually is possible to debug using my phone, even if I get all these errors. The crashing seemed to depend on something else (some error I did not find because of all other errors in LogCat). Hence, this is not really much of a problem. It would still be interesting if someone knew what made this happen!

Comment: Not really. My errors happen as soon as I plug my phone into my computer, enable USB debugging and open Eclipse with LogCat. It has nothing to do with my code and a lot of more errors than the Facebook one pops up (there were large chunks of errors that I could not add to my post because of the character limit). Anyway, seems that this was not much of a problem, read my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. Seems like I have facebook and facebook messenger installed and both opened in background. Thus new arrived message tries to deliver its content to both applications. 
Anyway, you can filter the LogCat output to see only messages from your application. Just write your package name in the filter field "Application Name".